# how to create a FB like from my app to a post in a FB page?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read that:

```
1) Doing like to external url
The og.likes action can refer to any open graph object or URL, except for Facebook Pages or Photos.

 from SOF: you can only like Open Graph objects (URLs outside of Facebook) with this, not Facebook pages.


2) doing like to fb page 

Publishing
...it is not possible to like a Facebook Page via any API. You should use the Like Button if you want people to be able to like a page in your app.
```

The server return to the client some FB posts urls in run time.

So if I want to create "like" to a post in a FB page, I need to use the like button only?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot like the FB page by facebook sdk, you have to call browser with your fb page url on the click of button.

Comment: why not imitating the http request by the fb-like-button ?

Comment: do mean tracing the facebook call and try to place your own parameters?

Comment: yes. unless there is an easier way. btw I can use fb like button with dynamic url?

Comment: you can't do that because to prevent such kind of thread facebook regularly change the parameter name (every week or so they have some kind of naming convension)

Comment: cannot do what?  tracing the facebook call or create fb like built-in button with dynamic url?

Comment: you can trace facebook call but you cannot use it for long because facebook changes its paramters name constantly.

Comment: and can i create fb like built-in button with dynamic url

Answer (score 0):

U have to use FB api to use like functionality. You can customize the like button like change picture etc. for detail i will suggest go through the API manual from **https://developers.facebook.com/**